# how to render this partial in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

i am trying to render this partial of the association belongs_to and `has_many` i.e

my model is as thus

activity Model

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :talks
end
```

talk model

```
class Talk < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs :activity
end
```

in my talk controller i have

```
@activities = Activity.where(user_id: [current_user.friend_ids, current_user])
@talks = Talk.find(:all, :order => "created_at DESC")
```

and in view i have

```
<% activity.talks.each do |c| %>

        <div class="media">
          <a class="pull-left" href="#">
            <%=  image_tag(c.user.image.url(:tiny),:style=> "width: 100%;")%>
          </a>
          <div class="media-body">
            <strong><%= c.user.username %></strong> <%= c.details %><br>
            <small><span class="muted"><%="#{time_ago_in_words(c.created_at)} ago "%></span></small>
          </div>
        </div>


       <% end %>
```

this displays all the talk for each activity

how do i create a partial of `<% activity.talks.each do |c| %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a partial in

```
app/views/talks/_talk.html.erb
```

and call

```
<%= render activity.talks %>
```

This will render one `_talk.html.erb` partial for each talk in the `activity.talks` collection, which will have access to a `talk` variable.

Furthermore, you can optimize the code by preventing [N + 1 queries](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations). In your controller,

```
@activities = Activity.includes(:talks).where(user_id: [current_user.friend_ids, current_user])
```

Notice the `includes(:talks)`. Read more about eager loading in the docs linked above.

Comment: thanks a lot u saved my day icluding your extra tip of includes(:talks) one more thing is if in my _create.js.erb i do this ,     $("#chat").append("<%= j render(@messages) %>");
$("#new_talk")[0].reset();                       how would i render the partial you provided for me... thanks

Comment: If you fetch the talks in the `create` action (ie, `@talks = Talk.find(...)`) then you can do something like `$(<selector>).append("<%= j render(@talks) %>");`